# How to change height of the video in html css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I have to display video on my page with 100% width and 400px or 500px height whenever i am changing the height of the video it also changing the width that i don't want. and i have to also display full screen video mobile device also.

Please help me in this..

```
<div class="video-size">
<video  autoplay loop controls muted>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.video-size
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this <video width="100%"  height="400" autoplay loop controls muted> but same issue.

Comment: You can't change the aspect ratio of video if you apply `width:100%` and increase height it will work but with black space on top and bottom

Comment: so we can not give the specific height with 100% width?

Comment: No because video can't be stretched..yes you can resize the video but with a aspect ratio only.

Comment: Mr.Gaurav can you help me  with code.Please

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37019713/4119808

Comment: use fitvids jquery library

Comment: Please share the link Mr.Dhaval. If you have.

Answer (score 18):

Hope this will resolve the aspect ratio problem.

HTML:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="videos/Raindrops.mp4" type="video/MP4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
#myVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: adding  "object-fit: cover;" works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful
For reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/gyx94wqj/

```
<div class="video-size">
    <video  autoplay loop controls muted>
      <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>

.video-size {
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.video-size > video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because this css will technically stretch the video which is not possible.

You can change the size of video but only with aspect ratio. If you forcefully change the height it will leave blank spaces at top and bottom.

```
.video-size video
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

I have given height to video forcefully and see the example with black spaces : https://jsfiddle.net/ohk8w0s0/

Comment: is there any way to display video on full screen on mobile device?

Comment: because i have on section and i am using that video as background.There is some text on video.

Comment: so that video will display on full screen on mobile and text will display on center of the video

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use like below.

```
    .video-size
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.video-size video{
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, its because of the aspect ratio of the video elements.

Comment: but  i need 100%width also.

Answer (score -1):

```
.video-size
{
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: what does this answer means??

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. You are not able to do width to 100% and also have a set height with a video. (not with out borders)