# Setting video as div background and bring the text in front

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html5-video, css-transitions

I want to set my text background as video. Upon my trying I am not able to bring the text in front. The text always hidden behind. Another issue is that the video background is not responsive in smaller screen and it covers the whole screen. More so, it seems that the video's frame width and height are removed (e.g. doesn't play in origianl width and height reatio).

Could anyone please help me solving this problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-left-padding no-right-padding welcome-text video-content">
   <!-- Container -->
   <div class="container">
      <video autoplay muted loop>
         <source src="assets/videos/welcome_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <h2>Hello, I want to display this text, and play the video on background.
      </h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome-text {
    padding-bottom: 180px;
    padding-top: 180px;

}
.video-content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
video{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting`<h2>Hello I want to play this text and play the video on the background.<h2\>` before `<video><video\>`tags

I would also advice that parameters
Like height and width be
`width:auto;height:auto;`

Comment: Akanimoh Samuel Obot, Thanks for the answer. But it will not work and is not supposed to work.

Comment: Alright... I though the sytax affected the performance. I understand.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `z-index: 2` in the text so that it comes to the front of the video.

[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Regarding the size of the video, you have to define a size of the `div.container` and the

```
 video{
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     [...]
}
```

Be this example at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyx94wqj/)

I advise you to take a look at these two articles:

[video height](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_height.asp)

[how to change height of the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019446/how-to-change-height-of-the-video-in-html-css)

Answer (score 0):

Bring text in front of the video:

```
.welcome-text {
    position: relative;
    /* make it position:absolute instead if you want it to be centered as shown below*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Center text in the container:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.welcome-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Regarding making the video responsive and mantaining the aspect ratio, you have to figure out what's the aspect ratio. Let's say the video is 1280 x 720, then 1.78:1 is the aspect ratio. It means if the width is 100% the height should be 56%.

You can't tell the div to have 56% of the container's width, but there is a trick, you can tell it to have 56% of the width as padding:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```